# put_flash not works with configure_session(drop: true)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my phoenix project I have the following action in controller which is responsible for signing out user:

```
  def signout(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> configure_session(drop: true)
    |> put_flash(:info, "Signed out successfully!")
    |> redirect(to: project_path(conn, :index))
  end
```

The problem is that when I use `configure_session(drop: true)`flash message is not appearing on the screen. How can I fix that?

Comment: `put_flash` stores the flash in the session and you're dropping anything in the session on the next request. You could use `|> clear_session` instead of `configure_session(drop: true)` but I'm not 100% sure if it's the right way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `clear_session/1` instead of `configure_session/2`.  Using `:drop` on `configure_session/2` will completely remove the session cookie and no cookie will be sent with the response.

`clear_session/1` will remove all keys from the session, but keep the session cookie sent to the client.  So you can still add your `put_flash` into the session cookie after you have cleared it.